# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Tables

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Has anyone else ran across responsive tables not having consistent background color? When I load a responsive table on a small screen the table appears to be colored. But when I scroll across the table I can see that only the initially shown section of the table was colored. The rest of my table is colored the same as my `body` background-color. I would like the whole responsive table to be colored consistently. Anyone know how to do this? I'm giving an example of my table below.

```
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mb-0 bg-secondary">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Project
        </td>
        <td>
          Contributors
        </td>
        <td>
          Description
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Board Game
        </td>
        <td>
          John Doe
        </td>
        <td>
          Come play a fun board game
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please reproduce the issue here **as a working snippet**. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ProEvilz I've added sample code. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Bootstrap 4's .table-responsive class in your <table> tag?  Typically, you'd want to have <table class="table table-responsive">.

Comment: I've been looking at the w3schools bootstrap 4 documentation which suggests writing responsive tables similar to above. I've seen this form suggested in other sites as well. But I should've been checking the official bootstrap 4 documentation which suggests removing the wrapper div. Tried that and it's working now. Thank you.